# How to create reference item in a table under MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I wanna to create a reference in a table.
e.g. If i got a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id int primary key, 
    name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, 
    *......*
);
```

How do i create another table that can refer to the id and name of foo table?

```
CREATE TABLE goo (
    -- I wanna add reference item from foo table :-)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `goo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foo_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_goo_foo` (`foo_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_goo_foo` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`)
);
```

Then JOIN the tables in select query:

```
SELECT g.*, f.* FROM goo g
INNER JOIN foo f ON f.id = g.foo_id;
```